# Issue with pagination

Tags: technical-seo, pagination

I am facing a problem : When scanning the blog in Screaming Frog, several pages were found, at the end of the URL of which:

```
    blog?start=20.
```

The number at the end can be changed in the URL itself indefinitely. Absolutely, these pages must give `404` answer.

Question: What to do with such pages? Block in robots.txt doesn't feel reasonable. If it's important, the site is on Joomla.

Comment: It is unclear what is happening.  Do they return a 404 right now?  Do you actually have any internal links with these url (and param)

Comment: You have to configure a condition in the programming of your website so that 1) only allow pagination if there's a next page available 2) if the value is invalid, return a 404.